# Validate duplicate records in list

Tags: apex, class

I am working on deleting duplicate child records on contact merge.

Example: I have a contact C1 and C2 : (C1 has A,B,C records and C2 has A,D,E) records and now record A is the duplicate with same name. On merge I have to delete one of the record and that is conditionally based( Means A validate checkbox on C1 is 'TRUE', A validate checkbox on C2 is 'FALSE') I need to delete C2 here.

For the same I am able to get these duplicate records in a list and now i tried below code, but it is not working.

```
// getting duplicate records here...........
deleteList = [SELECT Id,Name validate__c FROM childobject WHERE Name IN : duplicatelist];
Set<string> DuplicateCheck = new Set<string>();
Set<Id> DupeIds = new Set<Id>();

for(childobject pcc: deleteList){
    // How do we validate records based on my checkbox here in if condition........
    if(!DuplicateCheck.add(pcc.Name))
        // this if condition is removing duplicate, but i should select which one to remove from duplicates
        DupeIds.add(pcc.Id);
                               
}

// Adding duplicate records to this to delete
List<childobject>  deleteList = [select Id
                      FROM childobject 
                      WHERE Id IN : DupeIds ];
delete deleteList;
```

Comment: How the validate checkbox in the contact is checked ?. Is it any automation already available for that?

Comment: They will be selected manually by users.

Answer (score 0):

Please fix the `Validate__c` field on `SOQL` query in your code and use that field to identify the duplicate records.

```
List<child_object__c> deleteList = new List<child_object__c>();
//To find duplicate child records use Validate__c field in WHERE condition
deleteList = [SELECT Id, Name, Contact.validate__c FROM child_object__c WHERE Contact.validate__c = False];
//Initiate the delete process
Delete deleteList;
```

Since as you mentioned, `Validate` check box in `Contact`record is already enabled by end user. So please run your apex code via batch in `week` or `Everyday` cycle.

Please let me know if it helps.